# How to use regular expressions in strings to select those characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How to use regular expressions in strings to select those characters.

```js
const text = `<p height="100" width="300"><span><font color="blue" face="Times New Roman">....some content....</font></span></p>`;
```

The string I want to select is **Times New Roman**

Comment: Which characters, and in what environment do you want to match the characters in?

Comment: @CertainPerformance   Sorry. Corrected question post.

Comment: In what environment do you want to match the characters in?

Comment: @CertainPerformance   JavaScript environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using regular expressions, use `querySelector` to navigate to the element with the attribute you want to extract, and then use `getAttribute`:

```js
const font = document.querySelector('font[color="blue"]');
console.log(font.getAttribute('face'));
```

```html
<p height="100" width="300">
 <span><font color="blue" face="Times New Roman">....some content....</font></span>
</p>
```

If your input is a string rather than an HTML element, use `DOMParser` to turn it into a parsable document first:

```js
const input = `<p height="100" width="300">
 <span><font color="blue" face="Times New Roman">....some content....</font></span>
</p>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, 'text/html');
const font = doc.querySelector('font[color="blue"]');
console.log(font.getAttribute('face'));
```

Comment: I want to solve it using regular expressions(regex).

Comment: Regular expressions are [not a good tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/) for parsing HTML. Since you're already in a Javascript environment, you should use the Javascript tools already at your disposal for parsing HTML instead.